# KMS Host activation "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Tags: kms

I recently upgraded (clean install) our KMS server from Server 2016 to Server 2019.
I've installed the KMS Host Key and Windows is activated. I installed the Volume Licensing Pack, and host key for Office 2019.

When I try to activate / configure KMS, it shows "Office 19, VOLUME_KMS channel" under Select Product. When I click Commit to activate the KMS host, I get the amazingly helpful

"The following error has occurred. Please resolve the error and try again.

Description:
Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

I can't find anything helpful in the Event Viewer, I'm sure I'm just looking in the wrong place.
Looking at slmgr.vbs /dlv, it looks like it is active, and working fine to activate Windows 10 clients, but Office doesn't show up when I run that command.